# csv.reader escape not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

So I have this line in my CSV file

```
zeroconf.net,TXT,rockview\032entrance._http._tcp.ietf98,"\"path=/\"",2023-05-14T01:41:55.954Z,""
```

and I want to parse it to this

```
['zeroconf.net', 'TXT', 'rockview\032garage._http._tcp.ietf98', '"path=/"', '2023-05-14T01:41:55.954Z', '']
```

with this csv.reader config, `"\"path=/\""` field was parsed well but `rockview\032garage._http._tcp.ietf98` was converted to `rockview032garage._http._tcp.ietf98` which not as I want

```
csv.reader(f, doublequote=False, escapechar="\\", quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

['zeroconf.net', 'TXT', 'rockview032garage._http._tcp.ietf98', '"path=/"', '2023-05-14T01:41:55.954Z', '']
```

Comment: What's the rule you want to apply? Either the backslash escapes or it doesn't, but that shouldn't depend on the column. The only contextual difference is within or outside of double quotes. One thought on this: Can you fix the code generating this? I'd also suggest using JSON instead of CSV, though there can be valid reasons not to do that.

Comment: you're right, the code which generated this data might be wrong, I switched to JSON, and it worked. Partial data in JSON: `rockview\\032garage._http._tcp.ietf98`